# Responsive web design 100% wrapper

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I recently read about that whole responsive web design subject, and have decided 
to try and implement it on a project I'm working on.

The issue is the fact that I'm using 1280 width as a base point.

The formula I'm using is

```
target ÷ context = desired width
target = element desired width 
context = my 1280 base point
```

Whenever the browser is resized that layout breaks, since context is no longer 1280px.
How can I over come this ? (See the code below)

If I set `#wrap` width to a fixed 1280px; wouldn't it cancel the responsiveness 
effect?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html {overflow-y: scroll; height:100%}

body {font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #616161; overflow:hidden; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; background-color: #eee}

#wrap {
    background-color: #eee;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden !important; /* FF scroll-bar */ 
    width: 100%; 
}

#side-bar {
    width: 17.890625%;
    height:100vh;
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}

#main-section {
    float:left;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:80.46875%;
    height:100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
}


</style>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
 <div id="side-bar"></div> 
 <div id="main-section"></div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @zjd thats not a way to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border and padding widths aren't being taken into consideration when it's scaling.

If you add this to your CSS:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Your padding and border width will be included as part of the `x%` and you should have no problem scaling.

You can add it too all elements like I did above, or just put it on `#side-bar`. I like using it throughout, it makes styling (especially for responsive) a lot easier.

Comment: Oh, and yes. Adding a fixed width would defeat the purpose of building responsive. For responsive, try to stick with percents and `max-width`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set #wrap with max-width: 1280px;

```css
#wrap {
   max-width: 1280px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Very easy change to my existing CSS. Thanks!